# Why the -u flag doesn't work for ps?

Tags: bash, ps

I'm executing the following `ps` command:

```
root@dor-desktop:/home/dor# ps u -t "$(tty)" -u mysql
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dor       2070  0.0  0.1  22436  5240 pts/0    Ss   20:29   0:00 bash
root      2411  0.0  0.0  56028  1916 pts/0    S    20:45   0:00 su
root      2419  0.0  0.0  19532  2276 pts/0    S    20:45   0:00 bash
root      2488  0.0  0.0   4108   668 pts/0    S    20:51   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --b
mysql     2607  0.0  0.4 146552 19024 pts/0    Sl   20:51   0:00 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var --use
root      2672  0.0  0.0  15268  1224 pts/0    R+   20:59   0:00 ps u -t /dev/pts/0 -u mysql
```

You can see that the command asks for processes who are associated with the current terminal and who's user is `mysql`.
But I get both types of processes!

How can I separate?
I want only the process who initiated by the user `mysql`.

I found the following command: `ps -C mysqld`, which gives me want I need, but I prefer to understand what's wrong with the first command.

Comment: Are you sure `mysql` is the user name, and not some variation thereof? and have you the EUID in place of the name?

Comment: I just replicated this on OSX, except I got `ps: illegal argument: mattdmo` when I put my username as the value after `-u`. If I put nothing after `-u` then I got a result similar to @Dor. This is using the BSD version of `ps`

Comment: @Dor what OS are you running, and where did your version of `ps` originate? I just ran your original command on Fedora 18 (GNU `coreutils`) and it worked exactly as expected - it only showed the processes associated with the user specified by `-u`

Answer (score 1):

> But I get both types of processes!

Quite surprising, considering that the man page says:

> Except as described below, process selection options are additive.  The default selection is discarded, and then the selected processes are added to the set of processes to be displayed.  A process will thus be shown if it meets any of the given selection criteria.

Comment: Irony doesn't work too well...

Answer (score 0):

As [HaukeLagin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) [explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77891/22222), that's normal. An easy way around it is to parse the `ps` output:

```
ps u -t "$(tty)" | gawk '$1 == "mysql" || $1 == "USER"'
```